# Maximize a figure on creation

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm using the below setting to maximize a Matlab Figure:

```
set(gcf,'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1])
```

Although it is maximized, but it is still not fully maximized like the maximize icon in the label (below)  is not on. 
[image]
And this makes me loose parts of the figure when exporting it. So I'm wondering how I can fully maximize it as if I manually pressed the maximize button of the figure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use some [**undocumented features**](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/minimize-maximize-figure-window) to achieve what you want:

```
drawnow
jFig = get(handle(gcf), 'JavaFrame'); 
jFig.setMaximized(true);
```

The `drawnow` is not obvious, but essential as mentioned by Yair Altman in one of his comments how to avoid Java erros:

> Another possible reason is due to [EDT effects](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlab-and-the-event-dispatch-thread-edt). The easiest solution is
>   to place a call to `drawnow; pause(0.1);` before you access the
>   JavaFrame functionality (setMaximized or any other Java function).

*Tested with Matlab R2015a on Windows 8.1.*

Comment: Nice I did not know about that. It also works for me on Matlab R2014a on Mac OSX 10.9.2

Comment: Works in Matlab R2015a on Windows 7 64 bits as well

Comment: why if I used `fig1=figure('visible','off')` and then tried to save the figure using `export_fig` to save it, it is not saved enlarged? but if I used `fig1=figure()` then it is saved properly.

Comment: I'd say without visually maximazining it (figure visible), it is not possible as the java frame is not active. But that's too much Java for me...